# java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.hibernate.search.elasticsearch.analyzer.impl.ElasticsearchAnalyzerStrategy.initializeAnalyzerReferences

Tags: hibernate, elasticsearch, hibernate-search

I am trying to integrate elastic search with hibernate search.For doing this I am using following maven dependencies.

```
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-search-elasticsearch</artifactId>
      <version>5.6.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

But while deploying the application I am getting below error.
 java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.hibernate.search.elasticsearch.analyzer.impl.ElasticsearchAnalyzerStrategy.initializeAnalyzerReferences(Ljava/util/Collection;Ljava/util/Map;)Ljava/util/Map.
I know this question has already been asked but I am not able to find out the root cause of error.Any suggestion..........

Answer (score 2):

You're using multiple modules of Hibernate Search, but without different versions (5.7.0.Final and 5.6.1.Final). Use the same version for each Hibernate Search module, in your case 5.7.0.Final:

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.1.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
    <version>5.7.0.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-search-elasticsearch</artifactId>
  <version>5.7.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```